# Vector Valued SVM

Tags: svm

Can one please refer me to a formalism and optimization algorithms of SVM which outputs not only 0/1 but a vector of 0/1's, i.e. I'd like to train multiple classifiers at once for the same input.

Thanks!

Comment: You kinda answered your own question: *train multiple classifiers*. If you want some kind of *structured* output, such as a graph, you need different techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most SVM implementations offer strategies or methods for multi-label classification;  [libsvm has details here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/multilabel/), and libraries like [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) (Python) have [wrappers and classifiers for this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html).  You can also train a SVM model to output probability estimates or distance measures for each class and use thresholding to apply multiple labels.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can train an SVM which can output vectors and more. As was noted by Marc Claesen such outputs are called *structured output*, and are formulated in terms of *structured output SVM*. It was introduced by Tsochantaridis et. al. (2004). Here is the link to the project which contains code and examples: [structured output project page](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm_light/svm_struct.html)

Comment: Could somebody elaborate why the answer was down voted?