# Good implementation of SVM with operator valued kernel

Tags: svm, kernel-trick, structured-svm

I've already come across the question [Vector Valued SVM](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72314/vector-valued-svm)
but the replies doesn't point to SVM with any 
[operator-valued kernel](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.97.9524&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

I understand that [svm-struct](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/tj/svm_light/svm_struct.html) can solve the same by solving an inference problem, but I'm interested particularly to the SVM implementation with operator-valued kernel. 
Does any one know existing implementation of the same?

Comment: I've already found an implementation [here](https://github.com/operalib/operalib) but it is not good enough; I'm searching for a well known implementation